# Не получается сделать аутенфикацию с помощью php и .txt файлов

Tags: php, аутентификация

Я хочу сделать аутенфикацию на своём сервисе через форму `main.php`, которую будет обрабатывать `login.php`, сравнивая пароли между тем который расположен в файле и тем который я ввёл. Я уже 10 раз проверил правильно ли я ввожу пароль в форме. Сравнивал между собой символы которые получаю. Но всё равно не получаеться зайти.

`main.php:`

```html
<html>
 <head>
  <title>Сайт для обмена сообщениями</title>
 </head>
 <body>
  <h2>Сайт для обмена сообщениями</h2>
  <form method=POST action=login.php>
   <table>
    <tr>
     <td><h4>ID: </h4></td><td><input type=text name=id></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td><h4>Пароль: </h4></td><td><input type=password name=pass></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td><input type=submit value=Войти></td>
   </table>
  </form>
 </body>
</html>
```

`login.php:`

```html
<html>
 <head>
  <title>Логин</title>
 </head>
 <body>
  <?php
//error_reporting(E_ALL);
//ini_set("display_errors", 1);

$file = "./ID/".$_POST['id'].'.txt';
$f=fopen($file,r);

$pass = file($file);

fclose($f);
if($_POST['pass'] !== $pass['1']){
echo '<a href=user.php>Аутенфикация прошла успешно.</a>';
sesion_start();
session_register(aut, $_POST['id']);

}
else{
echo '<a href=user.php>Логин или пароль не правилен. Попробуйте ещё раз.</a>';
sesion_start();
session_register(aut, 0);
}

?>
</body>
</html>
```

Содержимое `0.txt` файла:

ADMIN //Это имя
thepass //Это пароль

цифра в начале названия файла - id

Comment: trim() к элементам массива $pass применяйте. Если память не изменяет, в них переводы строк (как в файле) сохраняются в конце каждого.

Comment: Вам не кажется что это не самый безопасный и логичный метод аутентификации? Да и при большом кол-ве пользователей ведь файлом будет, жуть, и пока не зайдешь - не понятно какой кому принадлежит. Через БД, к примеру, не лучше ли? Или "особенности проекта?"

Comment: @DantheHat Я согласен что это не самый лучший способ. Я пишу этот проект для тренировки своих навыков в php, а не для реального использования. И я не планирую чтобы в проекте было больше 20 пользователей (исключая пользователя ADMIN).

Comment: @Visman , спасибо, всё работает!